# Is access-control-origin: * safe if session based auth is disallowed?

Tags: security, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the security risks of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin)

I just wan't to check I'm not overlooking something here...

If I set `access-control-origin: *` and **do not** allow session based authentication, it's safe for me to serve up private data when it's requested with an access token, right? I can even allow post requests. As long as a valid access token is given I can't think of any way to attack a system like this.

Is there a hole here?