# Why cross domain ajax post doesn't work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to form site1 from site2 . But I get errors and the answer does not come back , what am I doing wrong?  This is code ajax POST

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "site1/form.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: {a: 'a1'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('callback success');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(status + '; ' + error);
    }
});
```

and this is form from site1

```
$a= $_POST['a']; echo $a;
```

What could be wrong? Titles on site1 in .htaccess I ordered ..

Comment: what error do you get

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: first you have a relative url that points to your site,second does the ajaxed site allow cross domain acces?

Comment: can you try with curl post?

Comment: I get error 500 Server..

Comment: In .htaccess site1  this   `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST" `

Comment: "500" sounds like a different problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

In cross domain ajax request modern browser send a `preflight` request to domain before making a actual request with method `option`. If you define custom header (in your case you have defined `content-type`) than it will be blocked. You can allow all request or particular domain in your remote server to accept all type request(in apache you can do it in `htaccess` and in IIS server you have to change `webconfig.xml` .

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons. Refer [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Cross-domain ajax request are forbidden by default, you can enable them, but it's a risk, as any other site can access your data on behalf of their users.

Do refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014554/2252016) answer for security reasons.