# How to send a cross domain ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a cross domain ajax request but I am getting below error for this I have also tried the below code which I have got from the one stack article is it possible to send a cross domain request or not.

Code which I have tried for sending cross domain request.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://testdomain.com/config.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'rejected_by_loid=' + 1,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#survey').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Error on console log:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://beta.paravey.com/paraveyads/config.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to allow cross-domain ajax access on the server. Ask your system administrator to allow your connections to that server.

Comment: Do you control http://beta.paravey.com/paraveyads/config.php? If so, add the header to the response. If not, you need to look for a different solution, for example an ajax post to your server and then a  curl request from your server to http://beta.paravey.com/paraveyads/config.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it on top of config.php

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Awesome thanku for your valuable support :).

Answer (score 3):

You must define trusted domain names in http://testdomain.com/config.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://requested-domain.com', false);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://requested-domain2.com', false);
```

*The last parameter `false` disable overriding same header.*

Of course if you want to open your domain for all calls you can set:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer - you *do* want to restrict the domains allowed to reduce the (albeit small) security risk : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin