# Ajax, php CORS header

Tags: php, ajax

I got such an error.

Blocked request to a resource of another origin: "Same Origin Policy" does not allow to load remote resources `from https://test-domain.com/public/fetch_data.php/` (missing CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ).

I added code at the begining to my config file `https://test-domain.com/private/initialize.php`

```
$accepted_origins = array("https://test-domain.com");

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
    if(in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)){
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
    }
}
```

My question: Is it enough or is there anything else to add?

Comment: `My question: Is it enough or is there anything else to add?` Did you already test it with that code?

Comment: @Baracuda078 yes -> if ip for test `1.1.1.1`  there is error `HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied` (console->network)

Comment: Then what does`$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` contain? Echo it out or use var_dump()

Comment: @Baracuda078 I found solution `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975920/how-to-send-a-cross-domain-ajax-request`

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

[How to send a cross domain ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975920/how-to-send-a-cross-domain-ajax-request)

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`