# Trying to access endpoint from browser - bad request | identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an endpoint. When I hit this endpoint with the correct credentials, it works and I get a 200 using postman. The endpoint is part of identity server - connect/token. The bad request is failing on the pre flight from the browser.

I'm seeing this error in the console.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Seems to be a CORS issue. I have a c# asp.net core project.

Comment: Can you post the endpoint as part of your question?

Comment: What is the URL shown of the page in your web browser? What is the URL of the AJAX endpoint being hit?

Comment: Have you setup CORS in your Identity Server?

Comment: localhost:55555/connect/token

Comment: Is that the url of the page? Or the AJAX endpoint?

Comment: Ah sorry for not specifying. URL - localhost:8100 and the connect/token is the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you're getting that error then you want to figure out why you're doing a cross-reference request and fix it.

If you have a valid reason for wanting to allow cross-origin resource sharing (for instance if developing on a local react server), you [can install a chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) that exposes that setting to be easily toggle-able.

[It's not a setting you want enabled in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin)--I strongly advise you for security reasons to turn it off when you're on any site other than a development environment where you have a specific reason for needing it.

Comment: Getting this error now -  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400.

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm I would check that your local server (probably IIS Express in VS) is running for the second website--the one that localhost://8100 is trying to hit.