# How to make HTTP request to In Flutter Web

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-web

I was trying my hands on flutter web. I tried to connect a simple flutter web app I created to mysql database and localhost using the http package. However I dont get any data returned from the request method. When I tried to print out `snaphot.error` I got this: `XMLHttpRequest error`. I have this method in a `FutureBuilder()`

```
getMethod()async{
  String theUrl = 'https://localhost/fetchData.php';
  var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
  var responsBody = json.decode(res.body);
  print(responsBody);
  return responsBody;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this request on you web browser or maybe postman?
lets see the result

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340929/how-to-make-http-requests-on-flutter-for-web

Comment: I also faced this issue, i changed CORS policy from Back end then it work like charm!!

Comment: Hello @HardikBhalala what changes you made in Backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also Add the code below to your php file like so:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
....
code goes here
....
?>
```

I Tried this on LocalHost and it worked.

NB: If you're using nodejs install the cors() package and use like

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Check out the [CORS package on npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: Thxs, this worked for me.  All my flutter side API calls are going thru php scripts to "get" data.  Is there any "gotchas" one should be aware of using this solution?

Comment: @Soccerjf Read More Here [On Safety of CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014554/9398610)

Comment: where should i add this php snippet, i don't have a `.php` file in my flutter web project. should i add it to the `index.html` instead?

Answer (score 3):

I literally just stumbled over the error myself. You are falling afoul of CORS... if you trace the underlying network traffic, you should see that it sends an `OPTIONS` request first.

To get it to "work" temporarily, you can launch Chrome with CORS turned off. Obviously, this is not a long term solution, but it should get you going. The command you need is:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Comment: Am on windows so ran this but this doesnt seem to work for me still `start  Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir`

Comment: Mmm... not sure. I wonder if the same options apply to windows. It definitely fixed the same symptoms for me on the Mac

Comment: not work for me . Env: Mac 10.14.6 , Chrome  80.0.3987.10

Comment: `open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security` worked for me on MAC!

Comment: I'm searching for a good approach/long term solution. Can you explain or link any helpful references?

Answer (score 0):

What I found out and solved the issue is

For Accessing a website made by flutter basically you are calling a JS script

and for any website to give access to a script (which in my case was another website I was accessing the api from ) you need to give some sort of clearance to access

Which is in this case is **CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**

Add below code to your websites `.htaccess` file

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www.)?(localhost:55538|somedomain.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
</ifModule>
```

adding this **will now grant access to your flutter website to hit requests to your apis**

Comment: I added .htaccess file above pubspec.yaml file with above content but still getting CORS error while running on localhost

Comment: Where is the htaccess file?

Comment: it should be present on top of your file structure

Comment: I can't find the .htaccess file.

Comment: the file should be present on your server, and if it's not then you should create one and paste the content shown above

Comment: Hey @VickySalunkhe thanks for the reply, but my web app is hosted in s3, so there is no .htaccess file. Should i still forcefully add one?

Comment: Also, I am running into this issue while I am trying to test the app and I am getting the issue, so should I disable CORS on my chrome? and once it is deployed to server with "HTTPS" it wont give me the error?

Comment: The answer is useful if you are trying to call some other website of yours from flutter web, so you need to add `.htaccess` file in that domain. or may  be you are facing some other issue, which is not related to this question, so do share that too. and if `HTTPS` is working then go with it.

Comment: where do i find/add `.htaccess` in my localhost?