# How to make HTTP Requests on Flutter For Web?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am building an application that executes HTTP requests to a NodeJS Server but when i execute an HTTP request the result is the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart:sdk_internal 41864:30                                    get current
package:http/src/packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22  <fn>
dart:sdk_internal 99587:96                                    <fn>


    at Object.dart.createErrorWithStack (dart_sdk.js:4617)
    at Object.async._rethrow (dart_sdk.js:28723)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (dart_sdk.js:28719)
    at Object.async._microtaskLoop (dart_sdk.js:25352)
    at async._startMicrotaskLoop (dart_sdk.js:25358)
    at dart_sdk.js:25433
```

Here is the code i use to make HTTP requests using `'package:http/http.dart' as http;` :

```
void requestGet(String endpoint, Callback cb) async {
    return await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url + endpoint),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}).then((http.Response response) {
      print(response.body);
    });
  }

  void requestPost(String endpoint, Map data, Callback cb) async {
    return await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url + endpoint),
        body: data,
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}).then((http.Response response) {
      print(response.body);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems reguarding the HTTP requests were solved by enabling CORS in my NodeJS Server [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) is the documentation.

Comment: Can you explain what this issue is, and is it a flutter specific issue?

We're calling an API using python and flutter ate different devices and the one with python is working fine but the flutter is giving this error `XMLHttpRequest error`

Comment: No usually, it's not a flutter specific issue it happened to me even in NodeJS, I am not extremely experienced in these type of issues, I suggest you to make a question and see what people tell you, thanks for reaching out anyways!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP.
Add below code to your .htaccess file (located in root folder)

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www.)?(localhost:CHANGE_THIS_WITH_PORT_NUMBER|somedomain.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
</ifModule>
```