# How can I get data from google url in flutter web

Tags: flutter, http, web, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web

I use package [http]https://pub.dev/packages/http to get data from this url https://trends.google.com.vn/trends/api/stories/VN_lnk_GMomYwEwAAA_GM_vi?hl=en-US&tz=-420

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = "https://trends.google.com.vn/trends/api/stories/VN_lnk_GMomYwEwAAA_GM_vi?hl=en-US&tz=-420";
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
```

Then it throw error:

```
Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54796/m1rEikri7V4=/ws
/
/home
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/dio/src/adapters/browser_adapter.dart 79:20                                                                           <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1446:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 150:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 703:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 732:32                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 526:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1302:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37312:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:4368:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:38289:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:38283:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:38115:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:38121:13)
    at http://localhost:54668/dart_sdk.js:33618:9
```

I tested with other work well. How can I get data from this url ?

Comment: Could you paste the exact error message you get please.

Comment: I have already updated error message.

Comment: You get an error from the dio package while you said that you are using the http package ?

Comment: They are the same, dio package is wraped http

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest error normally means your Cors policy is not configured correctly.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139505/how-to-make-http-request-to-in-flutter-web)

Comment: Do you try to request with my url?