# Running Flutter in WEB : Error: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I build an application in Flutter that is working perfectly as a Android App, but when I am trying to run the same application in the Chrome i'm receiving the below error. As you can see in the error i don't have any reference to my code, just for "dart-sdk/lib".

How can i solve this problem ?

**** Error message ****

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...

Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52742/ewRwL069luw=/ws

Running with unsound null safety

For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52742/ewRwL069luw=/ws

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current

packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1446:54                                              runUnary

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 150:18                                        handleValue

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 703:44                                        handleValueCallback

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 732:32                                        _propagateToListeners

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 526:7                                         [_complete]

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1302:7                                             <fn>

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 324:14  _checkAndCall

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:39  dcall

C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37312:58                              <fn>


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:4368:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:38289:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:38283:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:38115:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:38121:13)
    at http://localhost:52678/dart_sdk.js:33618:9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making network requests?

If so, you need to change the CORS policy on your backend to allow that.

[View here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139505/how-to-make-http-request-to-in-flutter-web/59552060#59552060)