# Why Flutter Web does not proceed HTTP request

Tags: flutter, fastapi

I have problem to proceed HTTP request from Browser with Flutter Web Application

### ERROR MESSAGE

**BACKEND**

> 127.0.0.1:52159 - "POST /signIn HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

**FRONTEND**

> ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/signIn

## My Code

**Back-End**

```py
@app.post("/signIn", response_model=ApiResponse)
def login(auth: AuthModel):
    response = au.signIn(auth)
    return response
```

- AuthModel

```
  class AuthModel(BaseModel):   
uid: str = None   email: str   password: str   name: str = None
```

- ApiResponse

> class ApiResponse(BaseModel):   message: str   description: str = None   success: bool   status_code: int   data: dict = {}

**Front-End**

```dart
Future\<bool?\> signIn() async {
try {
final response = await http.post(
Uri.http(\_url, '/signIn',),
body: authData,
headers: {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "\*"
}
);
print(response.body);
SharedPrefs.setToken(json.decode(response.body)\['data'\]\['token'\]);
return true;
} catch (e) {
print(e);

      return false;
    }

}
```

**Environment INFO**

- Flutter (Channel master, 3.12.0-11.0.pre.12, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-x64, locale en-DZ)
- Python v3.11
- FastApi v0.100.0

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804)

Comment: you need add 'Content-type: application/json' to headers in http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was solved by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68786561/13491008%5D)

The problem was that chrome browser have web security rules
you need to disable them if your server does not have SSL certificate.