# Simple POST request works in Postman but not in browser

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am experiencing an issue where a `POST` endpoint is returning a response when run in Postman but not when running it in the browser.

I have setup an API endpoint on AWS via serverless. Here is the .yml config for that:

```
service: tableau-export-rest

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  timeout: 900
  memorySize: 3008

functions:
  storeExportFiters:
    handler: index.storeExportFiters  
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /store-export-filters
          method: post
          cors: true
```

The endpoint resolver `storeExportFiters` (which is a lambda) for now just returns a success message:

```
module.exports = (event, ctx, cb) => {
  return cb(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      worked: true
    })
  });
}
```

When I deploy this to AWS and try hitting the endpoint from Postman via a `POST` request with no body or anything it sends me the response fine. When I try do it in the browser however I get a `cors` error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://myapi.com/store-export-filters'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:9003' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

Here is the browser code used to try get a response from the endpoint. I am using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for the http request:

```
  axios.post('https://myapi.com/store-export-filters')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I can't see why I would be getting a CORS error here especially as it works in Postman on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your API is not configured for cross origin requests. You need to configure your server to allow these requests.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will allow your API to receive requests from any origin, [however can be a major security issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin)

Configuring your API to accept requests only from specific origins fixes this issue.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: hostname:port
```

Comment: Why does it work in Postman then? Also I enabled cors in serverless so wouldn't that do it? I'm using lambda for the resolvers so there is no server

Comment: but the rejection is coming from the API, not the client - no?

Comment: No. The browser is blocking the request because it only allows requests from the same origin for security reasons.

Comment: ok, and Postman gets around this because it does not have an origin?

Comment: @redhouse87 did you get a basic understanding about that so far? i also reached the same conclusion as yours and curious about the same question which is whether a postman request gets around this.

Comment: @Nostromo It "gets around it", because postman is not a web browser, and does not care about CORS. Here is a good StackOverflow post about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486188/7800355