# Is CORS anyorigin allowed safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I just check our new website back-end code, and I found this:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
           {
               builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
           }));


services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], //--> AppSetting.Json
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], //--> AppSetting.Json
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

Is it safe or not?
Is User authentication enough if anyorigin is allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer: [What are the security risks of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin)