# Origin http://localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy error in browser when tried to call Spring REST end point in angular

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Getting below error when tried to call spring rest end point in angular.

```
Origin http://localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

**Error Image:** [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:** Add @CrossOrigin("*") annotation on top of respective Controller Class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using `CrossOrigin("*")` your accepting all domains.

which is not recommended and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-security-risks-exist-when-setting-access-control-allow-origin-to-accept-all) is why .

Using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`

will have the same effect for your situation and would only accept `localhost:4200` .

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to configure Angular to proxying call to the backend.

Take a look at Angular’s [Proxing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)