# Problems with fetch requests in svelteKit `/typo` 400 (Bad Request), Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: cors, fetch, sveltekit, 400-bad-request, sveltekit-adapter-node

I am currently creating a web homepage utilizing svelteKit.

I am creating a system where when a user enters the `/typo` path, they fill in the form on the page and when they press the `Submit` button, it creates and sends an email via Googlemail. However, in my local environment (development server), the emails are coming through fine, but after deployment, I am getting a `400 Bad Request` error.
Can you tell me what the problem is based on my code and screenshots?

I have set the deployment environment to `adapter-node` based on node.js and after build, I run `index.js` in `build` folder using `pm2`.

Why do I have this problem after deploying a feature that worked fine in my development environment (localhost)?

### the written code

```js
//svelte.config.js

import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter: adapter({
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: 5173,
    }),
  }
};

export default config;
```

```js
// src/hooks.js

export async function handle({ request, resolve }) {
  const response = await resolve(request);
  response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

  return response;
}
```

```js
// src/lib/server/sendEmail.js
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import { GMAIL_ADDRESS, GMAIL_PASS } from "$env/static/private";

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: GMAIL_ADDRESS,
    pass: GMAIL_PASS,
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

const sendEmail = async (subject, content) => {
  try {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: GMAIL_ADDRESS,
      to: GMAIL_ADDRESS, 
      subject: subject,
      html: content, 
    });
    console.log("Email sent: ", info.messageId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("sendEmail error: ", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export default sendEmail;
```

```js
// src/routes/typo/+server.js

import upload from '$lib/server/upload.js';
import { json, error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import sendEmail from '$lib/server/sendEmail.js';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { CAPTCHA_SALT } from '$env/static/private';

export async function POST({ request, cookies }) {
  const data = await request.formData();
  const captchaText = data.get('captchaText');
  const hash = data.get('hash');

  let userHash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(captchaText + CAPTCHA_SALT).digest('hex');
  if (hash !== userHash) {
    throw error(400, 'Captcha verification failed');
  }

  const name = data.get('name');
  const bookTitle = data.get('bookTitle');
  const email = data.get('email');
  const phone = data.get('phone');
  const inquiry = data.get('inquiry');

  const content =
`<p>이름: ${name}</p>
<p>이메일: ${email}</p>
<p>연락처: ${phone}</p>
<p>책 제목: ${bookTitle}</p>
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">오탈자 내용: ${inquiry}</p>
`

  try {
    await sendEmail(
      `[오타 제보] ${name} 님 | ${bookTitle}`, // 메일 제목
      content, 
      email 
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw error(500, 'Failed to send email');
  }

  return json({ message: 'ok' });
}
```

```html
<!--src/routes/typo/+page.svelte-->

<script>
  export let data;

  import BookSearch from "../../components/BookSearch.svelte";
    import ContentHeading from "../../components/ContentHeading.svelte";
    import SubmitButton from "../../components/SubmitButton.svelte";
    import TitleSection from "../../components/TitleSection.svelte";

  let captchaText = '';

  let books = data.books;

  let bookId = null;
  let selectedBook = null;
  let name = '';
  let phone = '';
  let email = '';
  let inquiry = '';

  const onSelectBook = (id) => {
    bookId = id;
    selectedBook = books.find(book => book.id === id);
  }

  const submit = async () => {
    if (!confirm('제출하시겠습니까?')) return;

    if (!name) { alert('이름을 입력하세요.'); return; }
    if (!email) { alert('이메일을 입력하세요.'); return; }
    let emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) { alert('이메일 형식이 올바르지 않습니다.'); return; }
    if (!phone) { alert('연락처를 입력하세요.'); return; }
    if (!bookId) { alert('도서를 선택하세요.'); return; }
    if (!captchaText) { alert('자동입력방지 문자를 입력하세요.'); return; }

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('phone', phone);
    formData.append('bookTitle', selectedBook.attributes.title);
    formData.append('inquiry', inquiry);
    formData.append('captchaText', captchaText);
    formData.append('hash', data.hash);

    const res = await fetch('/typo', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      alert('제출되었습니다.');
    } else {
      let errorText = (await res.json()).message;
      alert(`제출에 실패했습니다.\n${errorText}`);
    }
  }

</script>

<TitleSection title="오탈자 제보" />

<div class="about-mission-area pb-70">
  <div class="container">
    <ContentHeading name="오탈자 제보" />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="container"  style="padding:0px">
          <form>
            <table class="table" >
              <tbody>
                <tr class="table-row">
                  <td class="bg-gray-3 header-text">이름</td>
                  <td><input bind:value={name} type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="이름을 입력하세요"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                  <td class="bg-gray-3 header-text">이메일</td>
                  <td><input bind:value={email} type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="이메일 주소를 입력하세요"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                  <td class="bg-gray-3 header-text">연락처</td>
                  <td><input bind:value={phone} type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="연락처를 입력하세요"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                  <td class="bg-gray-3 header-text">도서명</td>
                  <td class="book-search">
                    <div class="book-title">
                      <span>{selectedBook ? selectedBook.attributes.title : "책을 선택해주세요."}</span>
                    </div>
                    <BookSearch books={books} onSelect={onSelectBook}/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-row">
                  <td class="bg-gray-3 header-text">오탈자 내용</td>
                  <td><textarea bind:value={inquiry} class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <!--captcha-->
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center mb-3">
              {@html data.captcha}
              <input bind:value={captchaText} type="text" class="form-control mt-2" id="captcha" placeholder="위의 문자를 입력하세요">
            </div>
            <SubmitButton onClick={submit} text="제출"/>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .book-search {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }


  #captcha {
    max-width: 260px;
  }

  .table-row {
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white !important;
    font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
  }

  .header-text {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. checked if it's a port forwarding issue for using smtp on the deployed server, but everything is fine.
2. Checked if it's a problem with environment variables, but it works fine in the development environment.
3. I tried specifying the server domain directly in the request URL in '/typo'.
   But it didn't work.

Comment: Since this is a CORS error, have you tried to attach an origin variable when you run pm2? Like ```pm2 start index.js --origin http://website.com.```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work ..

error: unknown option `--origin'

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add as many details as possible in the comment, but it seems to be better off writing it here. First, I don't think this is the issue from SvelteKit. More like a PM2 config issue.

To check if it's not, try run this command:

```
PORT=YOURPORT ORIGIN=http://website.com node index.js
```

If it doesn't raise any CORS error, got ya! If not, it may be indeed from Sveltekit.

First stop pm2, and disable your app.

```
pm2 stop index.js && pm2 disable [processID]
```

Add a config file in your app folder.

```
{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name": "from",
            "script": "./production/index.js", <- your index.js file location
            "node_args": [
            ],
            "autorestart": false,
            "exec_interpreter": "node",
            "exec_mode": "cluster",
            "instances": 1,
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "env_production": {
                "ORIGIN": "https://yourwebsite.com", <- ORIGIN
                "PORT": "PORT" <- Remember ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

(This is the file I use on my production server. You may need to tweak some settings)

Start PM2

```
pm2 start .server_config.json --env production
```

Remember `--env production`. Check if it works or not. Also, [don't add any catch-all * to Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Anyone can abuse your form and Gmail API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-security-risks-exist-when-setting-access-control-allow-origin-to-accept-all)