# Display cross-origin React error boundary errors with webpack devtool=eval?

Tags: performance, reactjs, webpack, cors

I just added an "error boundary" to my React page with the "new" `componentDidCatch` feature in React 16.

However, when an error is thrown it shows:

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

The React team [recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html#source-maps) I change my webpack devtool from `eval` to `cheap-module-source-map`.

This does indeed work.

However, if you look at the [performance chart](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), you'll see `cheap-module-source-map` is significantly slower than `eval` for rebuild time.

I can't afford to have webpack-dev-server run any slower. It already takes about 10 seconds to rebuild after a single character change to one of my JSX files. This isn't on a slow laptop either.

Is there anyway to display the error without changing my webpack devtool?

Answer (score 2):

There's been some discussion in [facebook/react issue #10441](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10441).

It seems that the problem arises under some very specific conditions. I encounter this error too since installing load balancer and reverse proxy on my dev machine, and I haven't been able to solve this issue to my full satisfaction without enabling CORS. Here is what you may try:

- try different Webpack devtools (from the table you've linked). For example,  for my setup, `cheap-eval-source-map` works fine, but not `cheap-module-eval-source-map`.
- set [`output.crossOriginLoading = 'anonymous'`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-crossoriginloading) in Webpack development config to enable cross-origin loading of chunks
- as a last resort, you may try to enable [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) server-side, globally or for specific routes, in development mode. Hypothetically, with CORS enabled you can use any devtool, alleviating performance problems, but...

  **WARNING:** enabling CORS this is a security hole and may be very dangerous, depending on what your security requirements are (see links below).

  Example of a simple Express middleware for enabling CORS on all routes:

  ```
  // Enable CORS in development
  if(config.IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
      next()
    })
  }
  ```

  You can make it smarter and only enable CORS selectively on bundle reloading routes. You may try the [expressjs/cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) package, which provides some more flexibility.

  Similarly, you can add CORS headers to webpack-dev-server [devServer.headers](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-headers-)

See also:

- [What are the security risks of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001269/what-are-the-security-risks-of-setting-access-control-allow-origin)
- [When is it safe to enable CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713644/when-is-it-safe-to-enable-cors)